# onchange not working with input field selected by class name

Tags: javascript

When I select the input field element by class name, the onchange event is not working. I want to change the value of the current changed input field. Codes are below:

```js
// change current input field
function upperCase() {
// change current change input field
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}   
// call function when current element change
document.getElementsByClassName('fname').onChange = upperCase;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
```

Please, I also want to change the value of the current change input field.

Comment: use event listener and i think it is better to use oninput listener, because it updates in real time, while onchange updates after input loses focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of elements, but you're trying to access the value like a single element.

You need to access each individual element, like this:

```
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
inputs[0].value = inputs[0].value.toUpperCase();
```

or even better would be to loop through them:

```
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
for (let i of inputs) {
  i.value = i.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

---

**edit** to add the event it should be the same idea:

```js
function upperCase() {
  // change current change input field
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
  for (let i of inputs) {
    i.value = i.value.toUpperCase();
  }
}
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
for (let i of inputs) {
  i.addEventListener('change', upperCase);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
```

Comment: How to add onchange event on it?

Comment: How to change value of current changed input field?

Answer (score 0):

`let x = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');` returns an array of objects, you need to work with the values of the array, for example:

```
let arrayFName = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');

for (let i of arrayFName) {
    i.value = i.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

And the same happens with the onchange property:

```
for (let j of arrayFName) {
   j.onChange = upperCase;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How to change value of current changed input field using upperCase function?

Comment: What do you mean by the current changed input field? When the onChange function fires, it will run the function you've defined as 'upperCase'

Answer (score 0):

Replace your 
     document.getElementsByClassName('fname').onChange = upperCase;

with

```
 const selectElement = document.querySelector('.fname');

 selectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
   upperCase();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others point out, when you have more then one element you should illiterate all and call function when it change. So basically something like this will do the work:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('fname');
for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('change', changeToUpperCase);
}
function changeToUpperCase(t) {
  this.value= this.value.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g,'');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
<input type="text" class="fname">
```